# Why 1's complement is not appropriate?

Tags: c

I was using `~` operator in C.

Now I assigned `x = 12` and print `~x`.

But it's giving `-13` as output whereas the output should be `3` (I think so) because after (12)1100 -----> 0011(3) (0's change to 1's and vice-versa).

Can you guys explain me this. I can't understand.

Comment: -13 is correct because the `~` works on all bits (the leading also) of your expression. If `x` is `int` (32 bits) the actual result is `11111111111111111111111111110011`. (I hope I did count correctly.) For what you might intend: Try to apply `& 0xf` to your result and you have the result as "4 bit number".

Comment: a) you're missing the remaining bits in your `int`; b) you're using signed ints, and the result is interpreted in 2's complement.

Comment: @Scheff a `int` is very often not 32 Bit, it can have any size from 16 to a infinity amount of bits

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 That's why I wrote "**If** `x` is `int` (32 bits)..." May be I should have been more clear: _If_ `x` is `int` **with** 32 bits...

Answer (score 1):

Your X is some variable which is aligned to 8 bits (8, 16, 32, etc).

When you write `x = 12` you set `x = 1100` (binary) for lower nibble but you set all other bits to `0`.
When you invert this, all other bits are also inverted and if your `X` is `signed` (for example char) you will get negative output which is ok.

```
//Assume x is char
char x;
x = 12; //00001100;
x = ~x; //11110011;
```

Thats why you get `-13` here.

Comment: I remember that 2's complement is "flip the bits plus one", so `(~x)+1` makes `-12`.

Comment: Wrong..there is no 2's complement when you invert bits, so result is `-13` if you print variable.

Comment: That is why 1 is added: `~x` flips the bits, _plus one_ is 2's complement. Try it; it prints -12.

Comment: Oh, yes, I do believe you. `~x` will be `-13`. Now add one to `~x`...it magically becomes `-12`. Just try: `printf("%d\n", (~x)+1);`

Comment: Yeah, we know that, what is your point here? I said, if you invert bits you get `-13` from `12` and this is done. End of discussion. What you are trying to do is not the same. No-one said you should add `+1` at the end!

Comment: `char` must not be signed, it can be unsigned, that is why there is the keyword `signed`

Comment: Thanks man but in signed int term -13 is 10001101 and not 11110011(which should be -115) i guess.. This is confusing me a lot

Comment: Where did you get that -13 is this you posted?